# Server refused post request in ASP MVC web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, http-post

I develop asp.net MVC4 ,and publish it in IIS7 on remote server. When I open browser on mentioned remote server and open my application all post request work fine but when I open my application in other computer that want to get reply from mentioned server, all it's post request do not work and their status are error 500.

[image]

I think that mentioned remote server doesn't accept post request from other computer and doesn't reply to them, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure request filtering, for example, with a web.config entry:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
      <!-- only allow GET,POST verbs -->
      <verbs allowUnlisted="false" applyToWebDAV="true">
        <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
     </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can see the official documentation and other configuration methods in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/